# Get furthest parent

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-8.0

Multiple row's of the same table can be related to each other by parent_id. Is there a way to get the furthest parent (with an additional condition, like `id > 12`) of a given row?

```
+----+-----------+
| id | parent_id |
+----+-----------+
| 12 |         1 |
+----------------+
| 13 |        12 |
+----------------+
| 14 |        13 |
+----------------+
| 15 |        14 |
+----------------+
```

- Given is id 15
- **Needed is id 13** (because it is the furthest parent with an id higher than 12)

Is there any reasonable way doing this in 1 statement instead of iterating over and over the closest parent again?

Comment: MySQL does not support recursive queries

Comment: @EriksKlotins MySQL 8 support recursive queries

Comment: Using version 8.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to find all the parents of a given `id` value, and assign a `level` to them to indicate how far away they are from the original `id` value. Then it is just a case of finding the `id` value which has the maximum `level` and is also greater than 12:

```
WITH RECURSIVE CTE AS
(
  SELECT id, parent_id, 1 AS level
  FROM data
  WHERE id = 15
  UNION ALL
  SELECT data.id, data.parent_id, CTE.level + 1
  FROM data
  JOIN CTE ON data.id = CTE.parent_id 
  WHERE data.id > 12
)
SELECT id
FROM CTE
WHERE level = (SELECT MAX(level) FROM CTE)
```

Output

```
13
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rxLgifhaZrvZWPbi8s423f/2)

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL 8.0, you can do this with a recursive query:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select id, parent_id, 0 lvl from mytable where id = 15
    union all 
    select c.id, t.parent_id, c.lvl + 1 
    from mytable t
    inner join cte c on c.parent_id = t.id
    where t.parent_id > 12
)
select id, parent_id
from cte c
where c.lvl = (select max(c1.lvl) from cte c1 where c1.id = c.id)
```

The recursive cte starts with `id = 15`, and then follows the relationship tree until the a parent with an id strictly smallest than `12`. We keep track of the level in the hierarchy. Then, the outer query filters on the record that has the maximum level.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=18e751f83a31588dd113bc2042eed7e3)**:

```
id | parent_id
-: | --------:
15 |        13
```